# How to get a file object from mkstemp()?

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to use mkstemp with Python 3:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Jun 25 2012, 23:10:56) 
[GCC 4.7.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tempfile import mkstemp
>>> mkstemp()
(3, '/tmp/tmp080316')
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/tempfile.html?highlight=mkstemp#tempfile.mkstemp), the first element of the tuple is supposed to be a file handle. In fact, it's an int. How do I get a proper file object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the documentation for `mktemp` you can see an example of how to use `NamedTemporaryFile` the way you want: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/tempfile.html?highlight=mkstemp#tempfile.mktemp

```
>>> f = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
>>> f
<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'w+b' at 0x384698>
```

This provides the same behavior as mkstemp, but returns a file object.

Comment: That's great. I wanted to use `mkstemp` because the file will contain sensitive information and missed that NamedTemporaryFile actually uses it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I know is using `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`, as you can see in @tordek 's answer.

But if you have a raw FD from the underlying OS, you can do this to make it into a file object:

```
f = open(fd, closefd=True)
```

This works in Python 3

Answer (score 0):

The int represents an **OS-level** file handle. What I actually need, is a more high-level file object. To make one, use:

```
os_handle = mkstemp()
f = open(mkstemp()[0])
```

Comment: `os.fdopen` does exactly the same thing as `open` except that it only accepts file handles, no file paths.

Comment: I don't think that's true: `open(0)` gives me *TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found* which is what I expected.  At least, I think counting on open to accept an int will not be very portable.  **Update:** this works on Python3, but not on Python2 (if you care.)

Comment: use fdopen kids

Comment: It seems that you need to use mkstemp()[1] instead.